# Prediction with coxphf

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis

I am wondering if anyone implemented a "predict" function for cox regression with Firth correction (package coxphf) in R.

Would  predictions with coxphf be computed in the same way those with coxph would?

Thanks!

Here is an example:

```
library(coxphf)
library(survival)
train <- data.frame(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3), 
          status=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0), 
          x=c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0)) 

test <- data.frame(x=c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0)) 
fit.coxph <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x, train) 
fit.coxphf <- coxphf(Surv(time, status) ~ x, train) 

predict(fit.coxph, test)
predict(fit.coxphf, test)
```

Comment: It's considered good manners to _at_ _the_ _very_ _least_ mention the package you are using if it's not in the small list of recommended packages. The very best manners are exhibited by those who set up a problem in code that allows testing.

Comment: coxphf **is** the package, sorry if it wasn't clear in my message. I am also adding an example to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After searching for a package with a function named `coxphf` and finding it in a package by the same name, I installed the package and ran the first example from the help page `?coxphf`. I then see that the results of the function is an object that inherits from coxph, so the predict.coxph function *should* deliver results and it does:

```
> library(coxphf); time<-c(1,2,3)
> cens<-c(1,1,1)
> x<-c(1,1,0)
> sim<-cbind(time,cens,x)
> sim<-data.frame(sim)
> myfit <- coxphf(sim, formula=Surv(time,cens)~x)
> class(myfit)
[1] "coxphf" "coxph" 
> predict(myfit)
[1]  0.7673587  0.7673587 -1.5347175
```

Presumably the author of pkg:coxphf thinks this is appropriate. Otherwise adding the class "coxph" would have been irresponsible.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it seems that this will only work to give you the linear predictors which can be obtained using `myfit$linear.predictors`. I am just unsure how to predict a new observation.

Comment: You understanding of the capacities of predict.coxph are incorrect. Please read the help page more carefully.  I suspect you need to change from the default for `type` which is "lp" to either: `type="risk"` or `type="expected"`.  You have not actually said what your expectation is. What sort of predicting are you doing?

Comment: It does't matter what I set type to I get the same error: Error in terms.default(formula) : no terms component nor attribute

Comment: Right. Failure with newdata arguments. Try `names(fit.coxphf)`. No item named "terms". So I guess you're stuck with pulling out the 'coefficients' and working with them.

Comment: Unfortunately, class coxph is indeed inappropriate. For example, terms(myfit) fails.

Comment: This has been recently fixed in the development version of `coxphf`: https://github.com/georgheinze/coxphf. Now, `terms()` works and therefore other types of predictions should be possible